# Aligning all lines of a text in the same column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap

The problem I have is that I am trying to align the next over the same "column". Take a look about what I mean:
[image]

But I'd like to have something like the next:

[image]

Just I don't want the text to invade the below area of the image.

I have the next code. What CSS should I apply?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <img src="image/bullet">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faq-panel" href="#faq">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed placerat dui non tortor volutpat volutpat. Aliquam dignissim ante ornare, finibus quam id,</a></h4>
    </div>
            <div id="faq" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">Suspendisse potenti. Donec porttitor id magna non ultrices.
</div></div></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us your existing CSS so we can help you more specifically?

Comment: I am using twitter bootstrap. The classes derived from there. The code provided is inside a "container" class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- Add `float: left` to the image to place it at the left.
- Add `display: block` to the text wrapper to make it be a block. Add `overflow: hidden` to prevent it from wrapping around the image.
- Add `overflow: hidden` to the `.panel-title` wrapper to clear float in case the image is higher than the text wrapper.

```css
.panel-title > img {
  float: left;
}
.panel-title, .panel-title > img + a {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.panel-title > img {
  float: left;
}
.panel-title, .panel-title > img + a {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <img src="image/bullet.png" src="[img]">
      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#qwerty" href="#qwerty">Suspendisse vitae tempor dui, ac ultricies purus. Proin ac lorem sed ligula pellentesque porttitor eu vitae magna. Morbi vel fringilla ex. In fermentum ex eget maximus euismod. Sed quis libero ligula.</a></h4>
  </div>
  <div id="faq-3mini" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      ttitor eu vitae magna
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works wonderfully! Thanks. I am learning design. A step further to know how CSS works.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table.

Something like this:

```
 <table>
     <td><img src="image/bullet.png"></td>
     <td>Suspendisse vitae tempor dui, ac ultricies purus. Proin ac lorem sed ligula pellentesque porttitor eu vitae magna. Morbi vel fringilla ex. In fermentum ex eget maximus euismod. Sed quis libero ligula.</td>
 </table>
```

But with all of your divs and classes included

Comment: Your markup is invalid. And html tables should only be used for tabular data.